Why subsample correlations change if I partition the sample in tails and body even if the full sample distribution is a bivariate gaussian?
I generated a data sample through a Monte Carlo Simulation where the underlying distribution is a “Bivariate Normal” with a correlation coefficient of 0.5, a mean of 0% for both series, and a standard deviation of 20% for both series.
Subsequently, I partitioned the dataset into three subsamples based on the values of the first variable: the left tail (first quartile), the right tail (fourth quartile), and the body of the distribution (second and third quartiles).
Why does the correlation coefficient between the two series change in these three subsamples, and why is it different from 0.5 (the value of the original distribution from which the data were partitioned)? I would like to understand it both mathematically and intuitively.

Baed on which quartiles do you partition? One of the two variables?

@JulianKarch yes, based on the quartiles of the first variable!

@JulianKarch i edited the question in order to specify better!

I answered your question at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/13317/919 with an example (using $R^2$ to express the correlation coefficient).  Consider also researching "Simpson's Paradox."

Because you introduced range restriction. The first two paragraphs of the following question might answer your question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/404954/173546
